# Sql - Duplicated variables entered into Mysql

Tags: php

### Duplicate Entries into Sql

Hi all, what am I doing wrong? I'm trying to enter multiple queries into my database. However although the correct number of queries are being entered, they are all duplicates of themselves. For example, if I add two items into my cart, one named 'gold', the other 'silver', only gold will be inserted but twice. Why is my foreach loop, looping the first item twice instead of looping both cart items into Mysql? My code works as follows: My CARTHANDLER is GET-ting the items details from the "product-details" page and saving the information as SESSION['cart']. Afterwards my cart2 page is using a foreach loop to echo out the item name. [This is so the user can add and remove products from their basket.] On submit, the cart2 page via FORM POSTS the data to order handler which in turn sends the item_name to Mysql.

My cart 2 page is:

```
                <form action="wp-content/themes/ravenyardantiques/handler/orderhandler.php" method="POST">
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
                    $total=0;
                    foreach ($_SESSION ['cart'] as $key => $value) {
                        $total=$total+$value['item_price']*$value['quantity'];?>
                            <tr>
                                <form action ="wp-content/themes/ravenyardantiques/handler/cartremove.php" method="POST">
                                </form>
                                    <td><?php echo $value ['item_name'] ?></td>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $value['item_name'] ?>">

                                    <td>£<?php echo $value ['item_price'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $value['quantity'] ?></td>
                                    <td name='total' value="<?php echo $total ?>">£<?php echo $total ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php if ($total < 1) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <form action ="wp-content/themes/ravenyardantiques/handler/cartremove.php" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="0"></form>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                            </tr>
                                <?php }
                                 }} ?>
```

---

">

This is my order handler:

```
session_start();
include('connect.php');
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {
$name = strip_tags(filter_var($_POST['item_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$sth=$pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO sold ( name) VALUES (:name)');
$sth->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute(); } print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
```

This is my carthandler:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
$checker=array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'item_name');
if(in_array($_GET['cart_name'], $checker)){
echo "<script>alert('Product is already in cart'); </script>";

} else {
$count=count($_SESSION['cart']);
$_SESSION['cart'][$count]=array(
'item_name'=>$_GET['cart_name'],
 'quantity'=>1);
    echo "<script>alert('Product Added');
    </script>"; } 

} else {
$_SESSION['cart'][0]=array(
'item_name'=>$_GET['cart_name'],
 'quantity'=>1);
echo "<script>alert('Product Added');
</script>"; 

}
```

If I use r_print - I get the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [item_id] => 233 [item_name] => A 9ct Gold With Sapphire And Diamond Cluster Ring. [item_price] => 260.00 [quantity] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [item_id] => 239 [item_name] => A 9ct Gold Ring With 3 Stone Amethyst. [item_price] => 200.00 [quantity] => 1 ) )
```

Comment: Why you are looping thru the `session` but inserting using `POST` variables? You are using same `var` in `post` for both insert queries.

Comment: It may be like this: `$name = strip_tags(filter_var($_SESSION[$key]['item_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));`

Comment: Hi Serghei, thank you for your input. I'm using POST as I've inserted the Session['cart'] into a form on my page "cart2". I will upload the cart2 code above.